# Rails app not recognizing the fastercsv gem on the production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I run the rails app on the production server, it gives me the following error:

> NameError in LigesController#export_all
>
> uninitialized constant LigesController::FasterCSV

However, in the development environment its working fine. This gem is already installed on the server. I can see it by "gem list" Any ideas???

Comment: hey its working now..i resolved it. I think there was a name collison. I just changed a name to something else and it worked. Thanx alot for replying.

Comment: Consider using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to manage your gem dependencies. Running your app with `bundle exec`, thus loading only the contents of your `Gemfile`, will help you avoid version conflicts.

Comment: I am using rails 2.3.11..i guess Bundler is not supported in this version??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this export all action in my controller. earlier instead of file I was using CSV, that gave me NameError. So i changed it to file and it worked. I dont know why we cant name it to csv..might be because of old csv gem...

```
def export_all

@liges = Liges.all

**file** = FasterCSV.generate do |line|
  cols = ["ID","Details","PartnerCode","Sence","Date","Partner","Person","TaxName","TaxID"]
line << cols

@liges.each do |entry|                
line << [entry.id, entry.description, entry.code, entry.ellipsis, entry.Date, entry.name, entry.people_name, entry.tax_name, entry.tax_id ]
    end  

end

send_data(file, 
:type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', 
:disposition => "attachment; filename=Oligo_data_#{Time.now.strftime('%d%m%y-%H%M')}.csv")


 end
```